# Remove line number option from grep

Tags: command-line, grep, command-line-arguments, alias

I use an alias for grep, that adds line numbers to the output:

```
alias grep="grep -n -I --color"
```

For a certain command I'd like to remove the `-n` from the grep command. I could not find a "Do not add line numbers"-flag. Is something like this available or do I have to add an extra alias without linenumbers?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use `command` to remove **all** arguments.

```
command grep -I --color
```

Answer (score 16):

Just use a backslash, as it will revert to the default `grep` command and not your alias:

```
\grep -I --color
```

Comment: So threre's no `--no-line-number` or like option?

Comment: grep without the `-n` flag does just that, the question was how to disable that default (alias), easiest way is the \ to revert to the original (not aliased) command.

Comment: oh that's awesome - i mean the `backslash` : did not know there were a way to avoid aliases!

Comment: Yes, very nice. Sometimes the simplest tips the best.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an older question, but I've been running up against the same problem. This solution works, but isn't the most elegant:

```
# Not part of your original question, but I learned that if an alias
# contains a trailing space, it will use alias expansion. For the case
# of 'xargs', it allows you to use the below grep aliases, such as the
# 'chgrep' alias defined below:
#   grep -l 'something' file1 file2 ... | xargs chgrep 'something else'
alias xargs='xargs '

export GREP_OPT='-n'
# Note the $(...) INSIDE the 'single quotes'
alias grep_='\grep --color=auto -I $(echo "$GREP_OPT")'
# Due to alias expansion, the below aliases benefit from the 'GREP_OPT' value:
alias cgrep='grep_ -r --include=\*.{c,cc,cpp}'
alias hgrep='grep_ -r --include=\*.{h,hh,hpp}'
alias chgrep=cgrep_ --include=\*.{h,hh,hpp}' # Not sure if there's a way to combine cgrep+hgrep
...
alias pygrep='grep_ -r --include=\*.py'
```

In the situations where you want a non-numbered output, unset `GREP_OPT` (or remove `-n` from it, like if you're using it to include other flags).

I've used `grep_` instead of `grep` in the above example just to show that aliases will happily chain/use alias expansion as needed all the way back to the original command. Feel free to name them `grep` instead. You'll note that the original `grep_` uses the command `\grep` so the alias expansion stops at that point.

I'm totally open to suggestions if there is a better way of doing this (since setting/unsetting the `GREP_OPT` isn't always the most elegant).

Comment: I realize `GREP_OPTIONS` exists, but grep's manpage states: `This variable specifies default options to be placed in front of any explicit options. As this causes problems when writing portable scripts, this feature will be removed in a future release of grep, and grep warns if it is used. Please use an alias or script instead.`